# yii2 SluggableBehavior is applied to only emty slug field

Tags: yii2, behavior

I am using SluggableBehavior in such way

```
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            [
                'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
                'attribute' => 'name',
                'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
            ],
        ];
    }
```

It works nice If field 'alias' in form is empty. 
How to ignore this behaviors If field `alias` is not empty on form submitting ?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Add `'immutable'=>true` in the behavour config.

The behaviour works in such way, that if the `slugAttribute` is not empty when `immutable` is on, that attribute will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

1. Configure this behavior with specific name:

   ```
   return [
       'slug' => [
           'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
           'attribute' => 'name',
           'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
       ],
   ];
   ```
2. In controller load attributes from the form (before validation).
3. Check if `alias` attribute is empty.
4. If it is not - detach this behavior (`$this->detachBehavior('slug')`).
5. Validate model.

Comment: Bizley !
Thanks for your answer. It is working decision.